# Kivy: absolute positioning with screen

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I created GUI using kivy. I based it on class "Widget". I positioned every item absolutely(coordinates and size). Its not responsive, buy it doesn't have to be. Everything worked fine but then I realized I would need another screen, so i changed class to "Screen" and "ScreenManager". Since I did it, everything is wrong. Previously coordinates (0, 0) were in left bottom, now they are in center. I had image whith specified size, now i can not do this. Is there any soultion to use code I already made, or it must be relative if "Screen" is used?

Previous (working) way:

Python:

```
class GUI(Widget):
    pass

class UpdaterApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return GUI()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    UpdaterApp().run()
```

kv:

```
<GUI>:

    Label:
        pos: 340, 660
        text: "IO"
        font_size: 80
    Label:
        pos: 340, 600
        text: "software update"
        font_size: 40
    Image:
        pos: 50, 600
        size: 180, 180
        source: "img/logo.png"
```

New (not working) way:

Python:

```
Window.size = (1400, 800)
Window.minimum_width = 1400
Window.minimum_height = 800

class GUI(Screen):
    pass

class NewWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class UpdaterApp(App):
    def build(self):
        wm = WindowManager()
        wm.add_widget(GUI(name="main"))
        wm.add_widget(NewWindow(name="new"))
        wm.current = "main"
        return wm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    UpdaterApp().run()
```

kv:

```
WindowManager:
    GUI:
    NewWindow:

<GUI>:
    Label:
        pos: 340, 660
        text: "IO"
        font_size: 80
    Label:
        pos: 340, 600
        text: "software update"
        font_size: 40
    Image:
        pos: 50, 600
        size: 180, 180
        source: "img/logo.png"

<NewWindow>:
    Button:
        text: "Go Back"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must use relative coordinates since the `Screen` is a `RelativeLayout` (See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.relativelayout.html#module-kivy.uix.relativelayout)). Also, when using a `Layout`, children `Widgets` get the default `size_hint` of `(1,1)`, which means that they will fill their parent. See the [Widget documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html?highlight=size_hint), and take note of the section discussing `default values`. If you want to use the `size` property, you must set `size_hint` to `None, None` (`size_hint` takes priority of `size` in the `Layout` container classes). Here is a modified version of your `kv` that demonstrates this:

```
<GUI>:
    Label:
        pos: 340, 600
        text: "IO"
        font_size: 80
        size_hint: None, None
        size: self.texture_size  # set Label size just big enough to hold text
    Label:
        pos: 340, 600
        text: "software update"
        font_size: 40
        size_hint: None, None
        size: self.texture_size  # set Label size just big enough to hold text
    Image:
        pos: 50,600
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 180, 180
        source: "img/logo.png"
```